# User Training tool for editing

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing a post another one appeared when I was finished. This second post was difficult to comprehend so much I didn't know who was posting and who was attempting an edit. Of course it is marked, but again both were such a mess (I suspected maybe ESL?) that I decided to attempt an edit so I could see what the result was going to be.

I was given a notice that this was some sort of system test that indicated I was in error in editing what was an attempt to deface a post. It pointed out my failure, but I intended on cancelling this edit, but wasn't given the chance.

Maybe this could be adjusted so it waits until the laast step before assuming someone is making an error? This is the only feedback I've ever had for my reviews. Now I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly at all.

Here was the post:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/37888?&_suid=137754344440002838923626941225

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I'm not asking to get rid of the whole process, just don't assume I'm actually going to do an edit until I hit save. The other question still wants to make a change.